# UIVisualEffects on device rotation animates views out of sync

Tags: objective-c, autolayout, screen-orientation, uivisualeffectview

I have created a vibrancy effect view o top of a blurred view. This vibrancy effect views has a label. I am using storyboard and have added all the required constraints. 
Everything works fine. But on rotating the device, during animation the views just don't animate together.  Refer the screen shots. One for, before the orientation change, the other during the animation, and one after the orientation change.[image]
[image][image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I tried to change constraints between UIImage and UIVisualEffect to be linked together and did not work.